# Azure SQL with Azure Active Directory authentication - use in security function for row-level security

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, row-level-security

We have a Azure SQL database using Azure AD authentication.  This all works fine for both Member and Guest AD users, and with AD Groups.

We need to apply row-level security to some tables, based on:

1. whether the user has ownership (or at least CREATE USER permission) over the database, or
2. based on the AD group

We have created a table-valued function for use in the appropriate security policy.
Problem:

1. how can we establish whether the user has ownership over the database within the function (which has to be defined `with schemabinding`)?
   Looking up permissions using `sys.fn_my_permissions` is refused as `sys` functions can't be used `with schemabinding`.
2. how can we query what AD groups the user is a member of?

Or do we need to maintain tables of the relationships within the database (with attendant multiple maintenance - AD + several databases)?

Answer (score 0):

The system function `is_member('<AD Group>')` can be used to verify whether the current user is a member of an AD group as long as that AD Group has been added to the database as a principal.
This function also works for database roles.

So security function like this works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fUserCanAccess](@Group varchar(50))
   RETURNS TABLE
   WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN (
   SELECT 1 as canAccess WHERE
      is_member('db_owner') = 1
   or
      is_member(@Group) = 1
;
```

The first `is_member` tests for a database role that allows access to all rows. The second `is_member` tests for the user being in the same (AD) Group.

`is_member(<AD Group>)` returns:

- 1 if the AD Group is a user in the database and the logged on user is a member of the AD Group (in Active Directory)
- 0 if the AD Group is a user in the database and the logged on user is not a member of the AD Group (in Active Directory)
- NULL if the AD Group does not exist or is not a user in the database

The Group name is NOT case sensitive.